# Java exception when checking if Integer value is null

Tags: java, null, nullpointerexception, integer

The following snippet of code causes my program the throw a null pointer exception and I'm struggling to determine why:

```
private void ...(){
    HierarchyForm hForm = (HierarchyForm)
    Integer id = hForm.getId();
    if (id != null && id.intValue() > 0){ <-- exception thrown here
        ...
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

When it crashes, the value of "id" is null. I know it's probably something simple but I can't understand why.

edit:  here is a short program showing it failing. seems to be issue with .intValue comparison http://ideone.com/e.js/H0Mjaf

edit: i'm building for java 1.6.0_45

Comment: Are you sure the exception is thrown at this line? This is not possible.

Comment: If the `hForm` variable is null, it would throw a null pointer trying to access the `.getId()` method of the variable.

Comment: @lakshman if that's the case, the code won't fall since it evaluates `if != null`...

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. It seems unlikely from what you've posted...

Comment: hform itself isn't null. just the hform id value. Integer id is being set properly.

Comment: http://ideone.com/e.js/H0Mjaf example of problem. it seems to be the .intValue

Comment: The only way to reproduce this problem is using the bitwise AND, it means, using a single `&` instead of two. Review your code and post a SSCCE and a stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

The line shouldn't throw NPE if id is null.

If the first operand of && is false, the second operand isn't evaluated and the result is just false.

Please recheck your code again and make sure that your are getting NPE on this line while evaluating id.intValue().

Comment: That was my thought, but I've tested with just "if (id.intValue() > 0)" and still get the exception

Comment: @pythonicate If `id` is null, that's normal that `if (id.intValue() > 0)` throws a NPE. However if your real code is `if (id != null && id.intValue() > 0)` then that's not possible.

Comment: Exactly. that is why I am confused that it is failing even with the id !=null check.

Comment: @pythonicate That can't. It's not possible.

Comment: @pythonicate looks like you're not executing the code you're seeing or the problem lies somewhere else. Again, post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Use This format to and find right solutions:

```
String id = request.getParameter("id");

        if(id!=null && !id.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            user.setId(Integer.parseInt(id));
            dao.updateUser(user);
        }
        else
        {
            dao.addUser(user);
        }
```

If use that one otherwise type format:

```
String id = request.getParameter("id");

        if(id == null || id.isEmpty())
        {
            dao.addUser(user);
        }
        else
        {
            user.setId(Integer.parseInt(id));
            dao.updateUser(user);
        }
```

It is simple, put a null check! Surround your object with if statement like

```
Object mayBeNullObj = getTheObjectItMayReturnNull();

if (mayBeNullObj != null) 
   { 
     mayBeNullObj.workOnIt(); // to avoid NullPointerException
   }
```

But, All of them giving a same result.

Answer (score 0):

Only way that this lines causes an NPE is for `id.intValue()` to be executed on a `null` element.

Java would not execute `id.intValue()` if `id != null` is false, because the `&&` is short-cutting the execution.

My suspicion is that your code actually looks like this:

```
if (id != null & id.intValue() > 0) {
```

whereas it should look like this:

```
if (id != null && id.intValue() > 0) {
```

Answer (score -3):

You need to write like this:

```
private void ...(){
  HierarchyForm hForm = (HierarchyForm)
  Integer id = hForm.getId();
  if (id != null)
     if (id.intValue() > 0){ <-- exception thrown here
     ...
     }
  }
  . 
  .
  .
}
```

Okay, I had not contemplated that the "&&" in java had this behavior to solve the first expression and the second only solve if "true".

In this case, of course, I'm agree with the responses of colleagues and assuming you have posted the code correctly, **my guess** is it has something to do with concurrent access to the same object hForm, some method may be assigning "null" for hForm or id.